# In LINQ, is join order important for where clause?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am creating a LINQ statement like following

```
from c2 in context.AspNetRoles
join c1 in context.RoleActions
on c2.Id equals c1.RoleId 
where c2.UserId == System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()
select new { c2.Name };
```

Notice that c2 appears first. The problem is the

```
c2.UserId
```

is not showing in intelligence. Is this a common behavior in LINQ. how can I fix the above LINQ statement, order is important?In `where` clause with `join` should have table identifier in the last in joining?

Thanks

Comment: I don't get you. If you want to return more than one field, you have to type it just like that: `select new { c2.Name, c2.Intelligence }`. Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: The order doesn't matter in terms of intellisense. Can you show what is the type of the `context.AspNetRoles`?

Comment: Why do you need joined c1 is you would like to retrieve c2.Name only?

Comment: @MaciejLos what want " where c2.field==value" how can I do this?

Comment: The above LINQ query works, right? What exactly are you trying to "fix"?

Comment: You can move `where c2.UserId == ...` before the `join` line if you wish. In general it could be in any place where `c2` is accessible and allows `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you well...

You can mix standard notation of query with lambda. So, if you want to filter `context.AspNetRoles` then join `context.RoleAction`, you can try something like that:

```
var result = from c2 in context.AspNetRoles.Where(x=>x.Field=="SomeValue"
                  && x.UserId == System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId())
join c1 in context.RoleActions on c2.Id equals c1.RoleId 
select new { c2.Name };
```

Answer (score 0):

Why join if you need only one value? Maybe try something like this:

```
var result = context.AspNetRoles
    .Where(o => context.RoleActions.Any(oo => oo.RoleId == o.Id) &&
        o.UserId == System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId())
    .Select(o => o.Name)
    .ToList();
```